# Is there a way to save 200 megabytes per second in a database

Tags: database

I am working on a point cloud generator in python, and I save my data on my local machine.
Each point cloud is 10mb after converting to binary, and I create 20 point clouds a second.
Just out of curiosity, is there a way to save the data on a database locally and eventually save it on AWS or Google cloud?
It would be 200mbps.

Comment: No point into entering binary data into a database. All ready made databases have a write rate amplification in terms of memory bandwidth or storage bandwidth you can't naively afford at these rates.

Comment: You may want to consider compressing your data first. Even just some simple LZ4 will get you a fast enough real time compression, and a much more hand able bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While databases like [Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance) can do this. Per node ingestion rate is 220 MB/s and per row limit is 256 MB. It is generally not recommended to store binary data in the database. A better practice would be to store the binary data in object storage such as GCS and then reference the URL of the object in the database.